# Вывести адрес, под которым машина отправляет запросы к 8.8.8.8 (DNS)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dns

**Задание:**

Выведите IP адрес под которым машина отправляет запросы к 8.8.8.8 (учитывать NAT после выхода пакета из машины не нужно, нужен IP адрес с которым пакет покидает машину).

Нужно написать Bash-скрипт. Как я понимаю, нужно понять где у нас в локальной сети шлюз.

**На данный момент готово следующее:**

используем tcpdump -
tcpdump -i any 'udp port 53' > whoIP - таким образом результат дампа со всеми запросами на 53 порт(т.е. DNS) сохраняется в файл.

Файл содержит следующие строки:

*15:09:44.365818 IP 192.168.0.102.11996 > 192.168.0.1.domain: 31675+ A? www.google-analytics.com. (42)*

*15:09:44.398267 IP 192.168.0.1.domain > 192.168.0.102.11996: 31675 7/0/0 CNAME www-google-analytics.l.google.com., A*

затем при помощи "Адского" выражения:
cat whoIP | grep A? | grep -E -o '>+ ([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}'| grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}"

Логика его такова:

1. cat whoIP |grep A?  - в файле мы ищем строки содержащие запрос на разрешении имени. tcpdump помечает такие строки A?
2. | grep -E -o '>+ ([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}' - данное регулярное выражение ищет IP-адрес в формате ipv4.
   в строке мы ищем следующую конструкцию "> "ipv4 адрес"" - в tcpdump ">" означает от кого к кому идет запрос. Нас интересует к кому.
3. | grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" - из найденного фрагмента "к кому" вырезаем только адрес.Данное выражение от предыдущего отличается лишь отсутствием "<"

   В целом мой алгоритм следующий:

1.Запустить tcpdump и перенаправить его вывод в файл whoIP

2. Послать в другом терминал DNS-запрос при помощи dig
3. ОСТАНОВИТЬ TCPDUMP ctrl+c
4. grep файл

Во-первых, проблема в том, что в скрипт данную последовательность я заложить не могу, т.к. tcpdump работает пока ему не послать сигнал завершения( вот тут и загвоздка).
Если в скрипте ищет запуск tcpdump, то следующие команды не исполняются, т.к. tcpdump работает бесконечно.

Подскажите, можно ли написать данный скрипт и вообще иду ли я по верному пути, в чем сомневаюсь очень сильно. Мне кажется, должно быть более простое решение.

Comment: [Вот здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369466/running-tcpdump-inside-bash-script) посмотрите выбранный ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Если это работает, то значит имеет право на жизнь. А tcpdump можно заставить работать как нужно.

для начала нужно его запустить в фоне

```
tcpdump .... параметры ....  &
```

символ & важен - он отправляет процесс в фон и можно будет продолжить скрипт дальше.

Так как нам нужно будет потом его остановить, то следующей строкой запоминаем его pid.

```
TDPID=$!
```

эта строка должна быть сразу. Иначе она запомнит другой PID. TDPID - это просто переменная.

дальше вставляете свой код. Когда нужно будет tcpdump остановить, просто посылаем ему Ctrl+C

```
kill -3 $TDPID
```

P.S. Важный момент, на который все натыкаются и долго не могут понять, что не так. В строке `TDPID=$!` не должно быть пробелов. Если написать так `TDPID = $!`, то работать не будет.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, я попробовал, но появилась новая проблема - tcpdump став фоновым процессом не пишет в файл при помощи ">". Также процесс не завершается при команде kill -3, только при команде kill -2

Comment: можно использовать флаг -w, который позволяет сохранить в файл. Правда в бинарном формате pcap. Этот файл потом можно "проиграть" тем же tcpdump через опцию -r

Answer (score 3):

> Мне кажется, должно быть более простое решение.

совершенно верно. если речь идёт о сетевой подсистеме программы *linux* версии выше или равной `2.0` (или `2.1`? никак не могу запомнить), то можно воспользоваться программой `ip`:

```
$ ip route get 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.0.2 
    cache
```

в приведённом примере вывода `192.168.0.2` — это и есть ip-адрес, с которым будут покидать систему пакеты, адресованные к `8.8.8.8`.

если полный вывод программы не подходит, и этот адрес надо извлечь, то для удобства обработки можно добавить опцию `-o` (*oneline*):

```
$ ip -o route get 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.0.2 \    cache
```

и извлечь его с помощью, например, программы *sed* (кстати, параметры `route` и `get` в данном случае можно сократить до одной буквы):

```
$ ip -o r g 8.8.8.8 | sed 's/.*src \([^ ]\+\) .*/\1/'
192.168.0.2
```

---

подробности смотрите в документации к программе *ip*: `man ip`, `man ip-route`.

---

кстати, маршрутов может оказаться и более одного (например, при использовании на данной машине динамической маршрутизации). они все будут отображены, и, следовательно, в окончательном выводе будет более одной строчки с ip-адресами.